# Update table in sql database from listview items

Tags: vb.net

Hello folks am trying read from the table identify a specific column if not YES then update my table using items from listview

```
Public Sub FeesFromSetFees(lst As ListView, Amt As String, Year As String, Clss As String, Term As String, Mode As String)
        Dim txtID As New TextBox
        Dim txtbal As New TextBox
        Dim toText As New TextBox
        Dim add As New TextBox
        Try
            con = New SqlConnection(My.Settings.DeseretConnectionString)
            con.Open()

        sql = "SELECT * FROM Fees"
        command = New SqlCommand(sql, con)
        reader = command.ExecuteReader
        While reader.Read()
            toText.Text = reader.Item("scholarship").ToString
            If toText.Text.ToUpper <> "YES" Then

                txtID.Text = reader.Item("id").ToString
                add.Text = reader.Item("balance").ToString
                txtbal.Text = CType(Amt.Trim, Double) + CType(add.Text.Trim, Double)

                Dim item As New ListViewItem(txtbal.Text)
                item.SubItems.Add(txtID.Text)
                lst.Items.Add(item)

                Dim lstId As New List(Of String)
                Dim lstBalance As New List(Of String)
                For Each li As ListViewItem In lst.Items
                    lstId.Add(li.SubItems(0).ToString)
                    lstBalance.Add(li.SubItems(1).ToString)
                Next

                Dim Sql = "Update fees Set class = @Class, year = @Year, mode = @Mode,term = @Term, balance = @Balance where id = @ID"
                Using cn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.DeseretConnectionString)
                    Using cmd As New SqlCommand(Sql, cn)
                        With cmd.Parameters
                            .Add("@Class", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Clss
                            .Add("@Year", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Year
                            .Add("@Mode", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Mode
                            .Add("@Term", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Term
                            .Add("@Balance", SqlDbType.VarChar)
                            .Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar)
                        End With
                        cn.Open()
                        For index = 0 To lstId.Count - 1
                            cmd.Parameters("@Balance").Value = lstBalance(index)
                            cmd.Parameters("@ID").Value = lstId(index)
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        Next
                    End Using
                End Using
                MessageBox.Show("successful")

            End If
        End While
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

I get my successful message but nothing really happen to data in the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Public Sub FeesFromSetFees(Amt As String, Year As String, Clss As String, Term As String, Mode As String)
        Dim txtID As New TextBox
        Dim txtbal As New TextBox
        Dim toText As New TextBox
        Dim add As New TextBox
        Try
            con = New SqlConnection(My.Settings.DeseretConnectionString)
            con.Open()

```
        sql = "SELECT * FROM Fees"
        command = New SqlCommand(sql, con)
        reader = command.ExecuteReader
        While reader.Read()
            toText.Text = reader.Item("scholarship").ToString
            If toText.Text.ToUpper <> "YES" Then

                txtID.Text = reader.Item("id").ToString
                add.Text = reader.Item("balance").ToString
                txtbal.Text = CType(Amt.Trim, Double) + CType(add.Text.Trim, Double)


                Dim Sql = "Update fees Set class = @Class, year = @Year, mode = @Mode,term = @Term, balance = @Balance where id = @ID"
                Using cn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.DeseretConnectionString)
                    Using cmd As New SqlCommand(Sql, cn)
                        With cmd.Parameters
                            .Add("@Class", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Clss
                            .Add("@Year", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Year
                            .Add("@Mode", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Mode
                            .Add("@Term", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Term
                            .Add("@Balance", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtbal.Text
                            .Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtID.Text
                            cn.Open()
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        End With

                    End Using
                End Using
                MessageBox.Show("successful")

            End If
        End While
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Folks thanks i made some changes to the code and it now worked for me.